# How do I compute the determinant of this?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

I don't get how I'm supposed to find the determinant of this when it's not even in matrix form.

Comment: HINT: compute the matrix form of $S^{-1}$. How is it defined on the canonical basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S\begin{bmatrix}2&2&2&2\\0&3&3&3\\0&0&4&4\\0&0&0&5\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
Let
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&2&2&2\\0&3&3&3\\0&0&4&4\\0&0&0&5\end{bmatrix}$$
$$SA=I_4$$
$$\det(S)\det(A)=\det(I_4)$$
$$\det(S)\times120=1$$
$$\det(S)=\frac{1}{120}$$